# How to use DFU on nrf51822

Tags: keil, dfu, nrf51

I use Nordic nRF51822 ble_app_uart project (pca10001) and new softdevice7.

I find a DFU project at nrf6310 directory of SDK .

when i program both projects the uart application stop running. What is wrong?

How can i update standard ble_app_uart application with DFU?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you disabled SoftDevice Protection? When programming the S110 softdevice using nRFgo Studio you need to uncheck the "Enable SoftDevice protection". Also, you need to have a recent version of the nRFgo studio application (>1.17) in order for the DFU functionality to work.

Comment: No it is not unchecked. What is the problem with this protection?

Comment: The DFU functionality uses a bootloader which writes to the memory areas protected by this "SoftDevice protection". This is done in order to modify the interrupt vector so that the bootloader is invoked before the application is executed. This way the bootloader can check if the application should run, or if DFU should be executed, for instance by reading the status of a button.